# Calling Python file in an Ajax Call

Tags: python, angularjs, ajax, http, flask

So I have established a pretty decent understanding of the simple architecture of an angularjs app, calling $http and posting to a php page, and receiving data back.

What I'm wondering, is how to do the same type of function with python.  Is it possible to have python act the same, with self contained script files that accept post data and echo json back?

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
```

type variable assignment at the beginning of the script, and:

```
echo json_encode(response);
```

type response.

I'm wanting to use Python for some Internal Tools for my company, as it offers better libraries for remotely running powershell scripts (as the tools are all linux hosted) and overall just has libraries that fit my needs.  I'm just having a difficult time finding a concise answer to how this could be set up.

---EDIT------

So I set up a quick example using the information below.

the angular:
        var app = angular.module("api");

```
app.controller("MainController", ["$scope","$http",MainController]);

function MainController($scope,$http){

    $http.post('/api',{test: "hello"})
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
        })

}
```

The flask:
    from flask import Flask, request
    import json

```
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/api', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def api():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       request.data
    return 'You made it' # Just so I originally could see that the flask page                    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I'm getting a 404 for that URL.  If I change the angular to look at 'localhost:5000/api' (where my flask app is running),it gives me the error of "Unsupported URL Type".

I am seeing when I do the first case, it tries to look at http://localhost/api , which is correct! except for the port.  Which is why I tried to specify the port.

Any suggestions for a next step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use flask.

You could host your app on a flask "server" and return the content you'd like too with a python processing.

http://flask.pocoo.org/

Use the documentation to setup a route where you'll POST your data using jquery or whatever, then on the route you can do your python stuff and return a JSON to your angular app if you need to.

```
 from flask import request   

 @app.route('/test', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def test():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print request.data['your_field']

        return your_json_data
```

Comment: so for the route I could specify something like ('/test') and then just have my ajax call use that as the url?  How do I access the request data via the flask route function (in this case test() )?  In php I would just look at $_POST[''], is there an equivalent in python?

Comment: That's insanely helpful! And on the angular side, I could just call '/test'? Or would I have to call a full url for that page?

Comment: Depends if you're on the same domain, IP and PORT, otherwise call a full URL but, no big deal I think.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: I edited my original post with my first try at this, attempting to use this information.  I know in php, I simply echo my response back, but it seems that in this example, instead, you return the value.  am I understanding that correctly?  If so, would I want to son encode the value before returning it?

Comment: Exactly, you return the value to your angular.

To encode you can use json.dumps but you need to import json first.